# Fancyheader placement on first section

Tags: fancyhdr

I have a problem with fancyheader. The pagestyle is defined like this:

```
\fancypagestyle{companypagestyle}{
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[R]{
    Page \thepage
}
\fancyhead[L]{
    Lorem datasheet
}
\fancyfoot[L]{      
    \url{http://company.com}
}   
\fancyfoot[R]{
    \includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logoCompany.png}
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{cyan}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{cyan}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}
}
```

Which produces perfectly what I wanted. The problem is the first section is somehow missplaced (closer to the header boundary than other sections).

It looks like this:

[image: First section placement]

[image: Second section placement]

Does anybody know what could be the cause?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide the document that causes this issue, not fragments only

Comment: We cannot reproduce what you show in the pictures, so answering the question is currently impossible. Please add a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) to your question.

Comment: Check the log file for a *headheight too small* warning. If there is one, fix it.

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you very much, that solved it. 
\setlength{\headheight}{25pt}

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm sorry for not doing so, next time i will attach the whole document. There seems to be no need to do it right now, as the solution is already there.

Comment: @tingdling: Well, this time could be solved by guessing

Answer (score -1):

> Check the log file for a headheight too small warning. If there is
>   one, fix it. – Johannes_B Jun 4 '17 at 9:22

This is fix. @Johannes_B gave the correct answer.